# How to remove the 'WARNING: CSS Error parsing':

Tags: css, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

There is a warning everytime I run the program, I don't know where the problem is because at [1, 19] of all of my css files I have a comment. I tried to fix this by removing the comment and it made no difference. Please help.

WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-fx-font-family: ;}: Unexpected token ';' at [1,19]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSnGM.png)

Comment: Seems like you declare a change to an attribute, but give an empty value.

Comment: The parser expects you to specify a value for the `-fx-font-family` property.

Comment: please edit your question to include your CSS file (or at least the part referenced by the error). it looks like you tried using the -fx-font-family property but didn't provide any font families as values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javaFx you can use CSS with two ways : you can customise your fxml file by using scene builder or by according a css file.I had the same problem ,when the JavaFX CSS parser encounters a syntax error, a warning message is emitted which conveys as much information as is available to help resolve the error. For example

> WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser declaration Expected
>   '' while parsing '-fx-background-color' at ?[1,49]
>
> The cryptic '?[1,49]' pertains to the location of the error. The
>   format of the location string is
>
> [line, position]

If the error is found while parsing a file, the file URL will be given. If the error is from an inline style (as in the example above), the URL is given as a question mark. The line and position give an offset into the file or string where the token begins. Please note that the line and position may not be accurate in releases prior to JavaFX 2.2.
Applications needing to detect errors from the parser can add a listener to the errors property of com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager. This is not public API and is subject to change. 
I think you add a value by using scene builder and you are adding `;` to your value and this is not acceptable in scene builder you need to remove `;`.
To resolve your problem ,go to your fxml file in your IDE ,i think you are using Netbeans and click right button of mouse --> edit , you can find your warning.